# Автоматическое обновление версии nuget-пакета при деплое из travis-ci

Tags: .net, nuget, travis-ci

Осваиваю публицкацию проекта как nuget-пакета. Использую `travis-ci`. В качестве основы для команды деплоя использовал [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509608/how-do-i-deploy-nuget-packages-in-travis-ci#answer-43880251). Но я бы хотел организовать релизы через github-релизы. Как я понял [отсюда](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment), довольно просто поставить условие деплоя. Но не могу найти примера, где проставляется версия пакета из версии релиза. Правильно ли я понимаю, что единственный выход - это подмена версии в файле `*.csproj`?

Comment: Возможно надо делать переменную с номером версии в ручную? Например: `script: - "make VERSION=$TRAVIS_TAG"` где и произвести необходимые действия. Также вероятно будет [полезен список](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) поддерживаемых переменных по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение вопроса:

`.travis.yml`

```
#...... другие настройки ...............
deploy:
    skip_cleanup: true
    provider: script
    script: chmod +x ./deploy.sh && ./deploy.sh $NUGET_API_KEY $TRAVIS_TAG 
    on:
        tags: true #важная строка
```

В `deploy.sh` нужно передать `TRAVIS_TAG`, я передаю его вторым аргументом.
`deploy.sh`:

```
ApiKey=$1
Version=$2 #принимаем TRAVIS_TAG

dotnet pack SOLUTION_NAME -v=n /p:PackageVersion=$Version /p:Configuration=Release
dotnet nuget push ./Path/to/bin/Release/GraphStructure.*.nupkg -k $ApiKey -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Здесь указываем номер версии так: `/p:PackageVersion=$Version`, где версия фактически равняется `$TRAVIS_TAG`.

Теперь, чтобы создать и отправить новую версию пакета - заходим в релизы репозитория на `github`, добавляем новый релиз, название релиза будет версией пакета. Либо добавляем тэги другим удобным способом.